Array-index-out-of-bounds error on shutdown in Linux with NVIDIA driver 535.171.04
When I close the Linux system, I get some problems：
[18124.593622] UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in build/nvldia/535.171.04/build
/nvidia-uvm/uvm_mmu.c:569:17
[18124.593629] index 8 is out of range for type 'uvm_page_directory_t **[]'
[18124.593651] UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in build/nvldia/535.171.04/build/nvidia-uvm_nmm_gpu.c:2614:71
[18124.593653] index 0 is out of range for type 'uvm_gpu_chunk_t **[]'
[18124.594663] UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in build/nvldia/535.171.04/build/nvidia-uvm_nmm_gpu.c:829:45
[18124.594665] index 0 is out of range for type 'uvm_gpu_chunk_t **[]'
[18124.596211] UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in build/nvldia/535.171.04/build/nvidia-uvm_nmm_gpu.c:857:59
[18124.596214] index 0 is out of range for type 'uvm_gpu_chunk_t **[]'

My computer has a dual-boot setup, with Windows installed on the solid-state drive and Linux on the mechanical hard drive. I pressed the restart button again, then re-entered the Linux system, and the shutdown issue was resolved.
My Linux:
Linux Big-Yellow 6.8.0-35-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon May 20 15:51:52 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

My NVIDIA：
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP102 [TITAN Xp] (rev a1)

nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI 535.171.04             Driver Version: 535.171.04   CUDA Version: 12.2 


(1) Please don’t post images of text, for various reasons; see: PSA: Please don’t post images of text.  If you can’t copy the text and paste it here, then manually transcribe it.  Post it as a code block.  (E.g., use “code fences” — see Markdown Editing Help and click on “show more”.)  (2) So, was this a one-time glitch, or does it happen repeatedly (and consistently)?        Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Report here or here: https://github.com/NVIDIA/open-gpu-kernel-modules/issues https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/gpu-graphics/linux/148 depending on whether you're using open or proprietary drivers.

Also, you really could upgrade to something fresher, e.g. 550.90.07 along with CUDA 14.0.
